# Python scripts won't execute when written outside of host computer

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

My ultimate problem is two-fold:

1. whenever I try to execute a python script by`./foo.py`  method, I get a `: No such file or directory`. However, I can execute `python foo.py`
2. when I'm not able to execute a python script using `./foo.py` I can't access it using Apache2/CGI (note that I can get this to work if I write and save the script within RaspberryPi itself, i.e., when I save this to /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ I can access this from the web browser (in this case, I change foo.py to print the appropriate html header))

In all cases, foo.py is executable and user owner is root.

foo.py =

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("foo")
```

What Works:

1. I open a text editor within RaspberryPi(and Ubuntu) and create foo.py (note I use RaspberryPi's Debian and a serperate Ubunutu 14.04 for cross-referencing/troubleshooting)
2. I can execute foo.py with ./foo.py  after I make it executable.

What doesn't work (part 1):

1. I write the same script on my Windows8.1 save it to a document folder
2. I save the script to the shared network drive /`home/pi` (I use Samba. smd.config is below)
3. While on RaspberryPi(or Ubuntu) I make the script executable
4. whenever I try to execute a python script by`./foo.py`  method, I get a `: No such file or directory`. However, I can execute `python foo.py`

What doesn't work (part 2):

1. I write the same script on my Windows8.1 and save it to a document folder
2. I open up FileZilla and sftp the script to RaspberryPi(and Ubuntu) destination is `/home/pi`
3. whenever I try to execute a python script by`./foo.py`  method, I get a `: No such file or directory`. However, I can execute `python foo.py`

What doesn't work (part 3):

1. I write the same script on my Windows8.1 and save it to a document folder
2. I wrote a batch file that putty copies (pscp.exe) the script to the destination `/home/pi` as well as makes it executable (I double check this on Pi side)
3. whenever I try to execute a python script by`./foo.py`  method, I get a `: No such file or directory`. However, I can execute `python foo.py`

In summary, when I work within the host computer itself, all scripts are happily executed. But when I want to work from my Windows8.1 and send via the 3 methods I stated, the scripts get angry and won't execute with `./`

Samba Config (smdb.config)

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   valid users = %S

[SnoopPi]
   comment= Pi Home
   path = /home/pi
   browseable=yes
   writeable=Yes
   only guest=no
   create mask=0777
   directory mask=0777
   public=no
   read only=no
   force user=root
```

Comment: Your Linux system should have commands called `dos2unix` & `unix2dos` that can convert line endings of text files between DOS and Unix format; both programs can convert in either direction (and are probably simlinks to the same executable).

Comment: This works. Thanks you. I added an official answer to my question.

Comment: No worries, JC Lee. I just mentioned those programs since they are often installed in Linux systems, assuming they'd be slightly more convenient than user3159253's perl script. FWIW, it's pretty easy to do the same thing as that perl script using sed, awk or Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to PM 2Ring

The issue does lie in the "invisible" line-endings that Windows adds. The solution was to download the (free) dos2unix / unix2dos Text file format converters from [sourceforge]. I executed the `<Path>\dos2unix.exe foo.py` while in the command prompt [1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/?source=typ_redirect)

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted so that this no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to select my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the problem is in line-ending. When you create scripts on "another computer" (presumably, on Windows), the scripts get windows line-endings ("\r\n"). When you try to execute them on Linux host, the interpretator "/usr/bin/python\r" mentioned in the first line can't be located by the system (quite obviously).

I recommend you to filter out all Windows EOLs by running something like `perl -pi -e 's,\r\n,\n' script.py`